# Can I stop stylelint extension from validating JavaScript file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, stylelint

Good day,

[image]

In above picture, stylelint prompt a CSS error in a JS file. Is there a way to stop stylelint from validating javascript file, I coundn't find such option in their [official configuration guide](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The linter can be configured to ignore specific files using the [`ignoreFiles` property of the stylelint configuration object](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#ignorefiles).

You can try ignoring JavaScript files with:

```
{
  "ignoreFiles": ["**/*.js"],
  "rules": { .. }
}
```

I believe the stylelint Visual Studio Code extension will respect this property.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Seriously, why does it even do this? Only option that works for me is to disable stylelint

Comment: Now it works after removing old extension from VSCode and installing up to date one.

Comment: Worked for me, I had to restart vscode for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this part](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#turning-rules-off-from-within-your-css) in the documentation.

You can specify `/* stylelint-disable */` at the top of a file to disable the whole file from being lint.

Or, better, juste specify `/* stylelint-disable-line */` to disable for a single line.

Comment: In this case, we need to manually disable the linting for all js files. Normally we shouldn't have any styling clauses in js file, right? Except for JSX.

Comment: This solution requires this comments to be placed in each and every JS file.

Answer (score 1):

[stylelint:validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tNED.png)
You can stop style-lint from VScode to ignore the javascript file too.

In settings search for stylelint -> at the bottom you can see Stylelint:Validate part. Select javascript and delete. It should fix your problem